# Find Customer from shopify with the particular range of date using shopify python api

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

How to import the customers from shopify with the particular range of date i.e importing the customers with the date filter ?

Please refer the code below for importing customers without filter:

```
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@%s.myshopify.com/admin/" % (self.api_key_shopify, 
                                                    self.password_shopify, self.name)

shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
customer_list = shopify.Customer.find()
```

Answer (score 1):

[As you can see from the documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer#index), the parameters you need to pass with the request in order to obtain customers created within a specific range are `created_at_min` and `created_at_max`. Unless you want to type the timestamps manually, we're going to need the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object from the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.

```
from datetime import datetime
time_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"
min_date = datetime(year=2016, month=5, day=1).strftime(time_format)
max_date = datetime(year=2016, month=6, day=1).strftime(time_format)
```

The formatting string we're using with the `strftime` method will give us our time in the format required by the Shopify documentation, with UTC timezone hard-coded in. If you want to use a different timezone, you can either hard-code in a different time offset, or use the [pytz module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

Now, for actually calling the API. When using Shopify resources' `find` methods, you pass property name/value pairs as keyword arguments, like so:

```
customer_list = shopify.Customer.find(
    created_at_min = date1,
    created_at_max = date2
)
```

And voila, this should return you a list of `Customer` resources, or an empty list if there are no matches.